# How to call a Class within a Class?

Tags: python

How would I call this class within a class? I'm getting the 'class' is not defined error.

```
class testArray:
    class testObject:
        blah = 0

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = 1

        # Problem here
        object = testObject()
        object.blah = self.number
```

Comment: You can access it like any other class attribute, but why is it nested at all?

Answer (score 2):

I think all you have to do is this. `testArray.testObject()`, and if you had a function in there all you would have to do is this `testArray.testObject.myFunction()`

Comment: that would only work if the method was decorated as a static method or class method.  otherwise you would need an instance to call myFunction() on.

Answer (score 0):

Further reading on nested/inner classes: https://www.pythonpool.com/nested-classes-python/

```
class testArray:
    class testObject:
        blah = 0
        
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = 1
        # just like other Methods
        object = self.testObject()
        object.blah = self.number
```